# How to add and remove one by one button from firebase db?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help in implementing how to make it so that when I click on the button, I add the firebase id to the database, and then delete it from the database on the same button
Here is my code, it adds but when I click again to delete it adds and deletes immediately
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktjY1.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)